# Velocity from velocity potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

I have this homework question and I get a different answer to the solutions.

In Cylindrical polar coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$, the velocity potential of a flow is given by:

$$\phi = -\frac{Ua^2r}{b^2-a^2}(1+\frac{b^2}{r^2})cos\theta$$

Find the velocity.

I get the velocity as:

$$v = (-\frac{Ua^2}{b^2-a^2}(1+\frac{b^2}{r^2})cos\theta + \frac{2Ua^2b^2}{(b^2-a^2)r^2}cos\theta)e_r + (\frac{Ua^2}{b^2-a^2}(1+\frac{b^2}{r^2})sin\theta) e_{\theta}$$

The answer misses out the second term in the $r$ direction, but I can't see where I've gone wrong. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For a flow in polar coordinates, the stream function $\phi$ leads to the velocities as
$$
v_r=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\theta}\qquad v_\theta=-\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial r}
$$
and not $v_r=\partial_r\phi$ and $v_\theta=\partial_\theta\phi$. Thus,
$$
v_r=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(-\frac{Ua^2r}{b^2-a^2}\left(1+\frac{b^2}{r^2}\right)\cos\theta\right) \\
 = \frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{Ua^2r}{b^2-a^2}\left(1+\frac{b^2}{r^2}\right)\sin\theta\right) \\
=\frac{Ua^2}{b^2-a^2}\left(1+\frac{b^2}{r^2}\right)\sin\theta
$$
and
$$
v_\theta=-\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(-\frac{Ua^2r}{b^2-a^2}\cos\theta-\frac{Ua^2}{b^2-a^2}\frac{b^2}{r}\cos\theta\right) \\
= +\frac{Ua^2}{b^2-a^2}\cos\theta-\frac{Ua^2}{b^2-a^2}\frac{b^2}{r^2}\cos\theta
$$
If $v_0\equiv Ua^2/(b^2-a^2)$, then the vector velocity is
$$
\vec{v} = v_0\left(1+\frac{b^2}{r^2}\right)\sin\theta\hat{r}+v_0\left(1-\frac{b^2}{r^2}\right)\cos\theta\hat{\theta}
$$

Comment: I was told that the velocity is given by $\nabla \phi$? This is how I got to my answer.

Comment: The definition of the 'del' operator that you mention is defined in the way @Kyle Kanos describes; it's different in [cylindrical co-ordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) from the rectangular co-ordinates

Comment: No, the velocities come from the curl of the stream function ($\vec{v}=\nabla\times\phi$). In 2D, $\phi$ is in the $z$ direction, leading to what I wrote.

Comment: @KyleKanos I think the OP meant "velocity potential" instead of "velocity profile". For the [velocity potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_potential), the velocity is found by $\vec{v} = \nabla\phi$ as the OP stated.

Comment: @OSE: OP states that "the answer misses out the second term in the $r$ direction...". Since he clearly took $\nabla\phi$, then the velocity potential is not what was defined above but the [stream function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_function).

Comment: @KyleKanos Nice catch! I didn't actually check his answer vs $\nabla\phi$ but assumed it was based on his notation. In my field, $\phi$ is typically velocity potential, and $\psi$ is usually streamfunction.

Comment: @OSE Sorry, my mistake, it is indeed the velocity potential not profile. Just a typo in the question.

Comment: @KyleKanos Sorry, my mistake, it is indeed the velocity potential not profile. Just a typo in the question.